# How to add a tabbar after a user action

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that doesn't have to show any tab when the user isn't logged in. I'm facing many issues with this functionality. First of all, I had embed the views, after the login screen, into a tab bar controller and everything was showing ok, except when I had implemented the login feature. As it's an async call, I had to wait until the credentials were validated. I wasn't able to do this in the `shouldPerformSegue` method or any other method provided by apple because you can't block the main thread until the async stuff is done, so the segue has to be done programaticaly in an IbAction:

```
@IBAction func doLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    userIsLogged = false
     let apiCall = webApi()

    apiCall.callCheckIsUserLogged(nil, password : self.passwordField.text, email: self.mailField.text){ (ok) in
        if ok {
            if(userIsLogged == true){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginUser", sender: self)
                }
            }else {
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock{
                    print("User not logged in")
                    self.alert.message = "Please enter valid credentials"
                    self.displayAlert()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this has driven me to another issue: after the programatic segue, my tab bar controller was disappearing, and after read a while it looks like the only way to avoid this is to embed your tab bar controller into a navigation controller. So I did it, but now, I got many new issues. First of all I got two navigation controllers, the one who is at the very beginning of the project and this new one I have embed into the tab bar controller. A picture will illustrate this better than my words:

[image]

[image]

Now I have two navigation controllers, and I don't know how to hide the top one. Already tried:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

But is hiding the arrow and I need to hide the other one navigation controller. But the best thing indeed would be to see the best approach for this kind of cases, when you want to add a tabBar controller embed into a navigation controller in the middle of the project.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can take another approach. Make login storyline and your app storyline distinct.

Have a storyboard for your login procedure, and another storyboard for your home (or whatever you like) and manage them in `AppDelegate`.

This is how i did it:

```
if /* user must log in */ {
    self.window?.rootViewController = loginStoryboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
else {
    self.window?.rootViewController = homeStoryboard?instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Put this code in a method (for example called `manageRootViewController()`) and call it at app launch, or after your login. (You can also add custom animations if you like)

Comment: looks like a very good approach, but I have a problem, my project is a bit advanced and I would need to copy/paste all the "logout" windows to a new storyboard, that sound pretty good, but storyboard doesn't allow copy paste... So If there is no other solution, I would take that one, but I wonder if there is really no other solution?

Comment: What do you mean storyboard doesn't allow copy/paste? I do it all the time . But anyway, If you're deploying for iOS9.0+, storyboards support [storyboard reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html). So you can just [refactor storyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/RefactorStoryboard.html). This is the cleanest way possible to distinct them, but I copy/pasted storyboards before (and just tried it) maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: But to answer "other solutions for adding tab bar" you can also have a `UITabBarController` from the beginning, just Hide/Unhide tab bar whenever you feel the best.